# shm_open() permission denied even with all the flags

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I'm trying to make a shared memory object with `shm_open` but I keep getting permission denied error. This didn't happen until I manually deleted `/shm` under `/dev` and then remade it again. (Could that be the problem? Do I need to set the permission on the new `shm` folder that I made?)

Anyways here is the code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void make_shm()
{
    int fd;
    fd = shm_open("NEW_FS", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("error when making shared mem object\n.");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    make_shm();
}
```

And heres' the error i get in the IDE:

[image]

Comment: `ls -Al /dev` shows `drwxrwxrwt.  2  root root  40 May  1 23:20 shm` on Fedora 29. Did you get the permissions right when you recreated it? (`t` is the sticky bit).

Comment: /dev/shm should also be mounted...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks but how to mount /dev/shm?

Comment: @jww yeah I changed folder permission after I recreated it and the error no longer shows thanks